# How to return the destructured objects from array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, lodash

I have an array of objects which looks like

```
const test = [{client: {id: "1", "Name": "peter" , marks: { subject: { english : 10 } } }, {door: {id: "2", "Name": "parker" , marks: { subject: { French : 13 } } }]
```

Now, In this array of object I have two objects and their keys are , client and door . now,

I want to destructure it like,

```
const [firstobj, secondObj ] = test.forEach(() -> {})
```

is there any way though which I can do it,

one solution is like `test[0].Client` , but is there another solution for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: const [firstobj, secondObj] is equal test constant exactly without any difference, please clarify more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do pretty much like you had:

```
const [first, second] = test;
```

```js
const test = [
  { client: { id: "1", Name: "peter", marks: { subject: { english: 10 } } } },
  { door: { id: "2", Name: "parker", marks: { subject: { French: 13 } } } },
];
const [first, second] = test;
console.log(first.client);
console.log(second.door);
```